# Changing column name in Visual Studio SQL feature

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I made the mistake of labeling 2 columns and putting integers in the titles and now I need to change them because they are obviously invalid. I just don't know in visual studio where I go to change this so it works across the entire project. I've changed it in the design view of the table but still get the error

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name '13DigiISBN'.

Comment: you can try using queries, you can find how to use alter command for renaming in: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/alter_table.php

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using SQL Server.

try this:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.[YourTable].[13DigiISBN]', @newname = N'NewColumnName'
```

Comment: I get an error saying Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype(COLUMN) is wrong. when trying this...
    exec sp_RENAME 'dbo.Books.13ISBN','thirteenISBN','COLUMN'

Comment: Don't forget to add the square brackets and try to add the optional argument @objtype = 'COLUMN'

Comment: Please check if your table contains another column name starting with '13DigiISBN'. e.g. '13DigiISBN_2'

Comment: no luck i must be doing something wrong, i scrapped the table and all and rebuilt it with the proper name criteria but have to alter 1 of my dataTypes because i just copied it over and changed names without changing a data type